# What's the difference between manipulating a prop using a constant vs. using a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In this approach, I'm checking if `propOne` is even and then assigning the result to a constant.

```
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = ({ propOne }) => {
    const isEven = propOne % 2 === 0

    return (
        <div>
            {`Is even? ${isEven ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`}
        </div>
    );
};
```

In this other approach, I'm doing the same logic (checking if `propOne` is even), but instead of assigning the result to a constant, I'm assigning it to a function.

```
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = ({ propOne }) => {
    const isEven = () => propOne % 2 === 0

    return (
        <div>
            {`Is even? ${isEven() ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Besides the obvious difference of having to use `isEven()` instead of just `isEven`, what are the differences between these two approaches?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference given that this is a function component. (Which means using the function is adding a small amount of verbosity for no gain.) But note that there would be a difference in a class component, if `isEven` referenced `this.propOne` and were used in (eg) an event handler that is called some time after the render - see https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/ if interested

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, it will.

Comment: In neither case does your `isEven` variable do anything at all.

Comment: @charlietfl, even if the prop changes, the function "captures" the value of the prop from that particular render. This is excellently explained by Dan Abramov in the article I linked to in my first comment (but it's ultimately just a "boring" fact about JS closures).

Comment: @RobinZigmond, thanks for the read. I think that what I was trying to ask was exactly what the blog post explained. Maybe you can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @pharoeste - thanks, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference, given that this is a function component. (Which means using the function is adding a small amount of verbosity for no gain.)

But note that there would be a difference in a class component, if `isEven` referenced `this.props.propOne` and were used in (eg) an event handler that is called some time after the render - see [this article](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) by Dan Abramov (one of the React developers) for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

The function approach will reevaluate the expression every time you access it. In this specific case, I don't see a lot of benefit since if `propOne` changes it will cause a re-render anyways.

Based on this specific example, just go with the non-function wrapper version